# Why can SpotBugs (FindBugs) scan Java Bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode, static-analysis

I always have the impression that static analyzers have to look into the source code to perform analysis, but how does Spotbugs analyze Java Bytecode? Isn't that a compiled source file?

Comment: Because your impression was wrong. If you can’t explain why you had that expression, we can’t explain at which point you made the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Java bytecode retains a lot more information then native machine code.

Class names, function names, call parameter and return types are all retained.
Thus it is much easier to analyze or decompile back in to source then hardware machine codes such as result from compilation of C.

Also, there is no reason that any machine code can't be statically analyzed, especially if it was compiled with debug information.

After all, the processor commands are documented.
Compilation is not a method for hiding what your code does.